# Where can I find the technical discussion between Satoshi and other contributors in the sourceforge website?

Tags: history, satoshi-nakamoto

Where I can find the technical discussion between Satoshi and other contributors in the sourceforge website?

I read the book of Satoshi in spanish and really excited about his comprehension of the economy especially for Satoshi. I was disappointed because couldn't find the technical concepts.

**I'm Searching the comments in the forum especially Satoshi with Hal Finney**

Where can I find all the comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org

I believe this group has attempted to consolidate all known messages written by Satoshi Nakamoto on their site.